# Каким образом получить название типа данных переменной?

Tags: rust, типы

Хотелось бы иметь возможность получать в название типа данных переменной.

Какие есть варианты решения?

Answer (score 2):

Одно из возможный решений:

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

pub fn get_type_of<T>(_: &T) -> String {
    unsafe { String::from(::std::intrinsics::type_name::<T>()) }
}
```